# Pandas convert rows to columns and columns to rows in dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have the following DataFrame:

| ID | Week | A | B |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 1 | 1 |
| 2 | 1 | 1 | 2 |
| 1 | 2 | 2 | 1 |
| 2 | 2 | 2 | 3 |

I now want to pivot the **mean values** in the DataFrame with the **weeks as columns** and the **former columns** as row entries **in Type**, so it can get this structure:

| Type | Week 1 | Week 2 | ... | Week N |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A | 1 | 2 | ... |  |
| B | 1.5 | 2 | ... |  |

Comment: Given that you apparently already know the term "pivot" then there really is nothing stopping you researching the huge number of answers that already exist for this. What is your research?

Comment: This is not really helpful at all tbh. I already tried several things with pivoting and looked through the forum.

Comment: You might want to update the question with the exact matching output

Comment: Related: [How can I pivot a dataframe?](/q/47152691/4518341) (though it's really broad)

Comment: Thanks! I'll look into it. Also the output has been updated now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need a `pivot`, use [`groupby.mean`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.mean.html) and a [`transpose`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.transpose.html):

```
out = (df
   .drop(columns='ID')
   .groupby('Week').mean().T
   .add_prefix('Week')
   .rename_axis(index='Type', columns=None).reset_index()
)
```

Alternative with [`melt`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.melt.html) and [`pivot_table`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.pivot_table.html):

```
out = (df
   .melt(['ID', 'Week'], var_name='Type')
   .pivot_table(index='Type', columns='Week', values='value')
   .add_prefix('Week').reset_index().rename_axis(columns=None)
)
```

Output:

```
  Type  Week1  Week2
0    A    1.0    2.0
1    B    1.5    2.0
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`pivot_table`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.pivot_table.html).

```
df.pivot_table(columns=['Week'], values=['A', 'B']).rename_axis('Type')
```

```
Week    1    2
Type          
A     1.0  2.0
B     1.5  2.0
```

The default `aggfunc` is `mean`, so It Just Works.